# How to run django project contains an docker file

Tags: django, docker, django-views, dockerfile

I'm trying to run my Django project

first time I'm using docker

readme file

**Docker should be running**

`` In the project root run `docker-compose up` ``

Go to `localhost` to view the project

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    entrypoint: "/app/run_server.sh"
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    restart: "on-failure"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    volumes:
      - ~/pgsql/quiz_bot:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - PGPORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres

    restart: "on-failure"

 # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    hostname: redis
```

*`settings.py`*

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': env('DB_ENGINE', 'django.db.backends.postgresql'),         
        'NAME': env('DB_NAME', 'postgres'),                  
        'HOST': env('DB_HOST', 'db'),
        'PORT': env('DB_PORT', '5432'),  
    }
}
```

I tried to do makemigrations but it shows an error like
RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not translate host name "db" to address: Unknown host

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What are your `DATABASES` settings in `settings.py` ?

Comment: `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': env('DB_ENGINE', 'django.db.backends.postgresql'),
        'NAME': env('DB_NAME', 'postgres'),
        
        'HOST': env('DB_HOST', 'db'),
        'PORT': env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

OK, from this `settings`

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': env('DB_ENGINE', 'django.db.backends.postgresql'),         
        'NAME': env('DB_NAME', 'postgres'),                  
        'HOST': env('DB_HOST', 'db'),
        'PORT': env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
```

It looks like

a) You're not actually using the env vars passed into the container, under the `environment` section of the yaml.

This isn't a major deal because you're providing defaults which are OK, but

b) You're missing `USER` and `PASSWORD` in the `DATABASES` settings.

You could also use the setting `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust` to allow all connections. This is fine for local dev, but don't deploy like this as it's not secure for production use.

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-connection-settings

Here's a quick tutorial as well: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-postgresql-database-in-django/

Something else to try:

Since there seems to be an issue with the "db" service, the only thing I can really think of here is the restart policy. Try removing the quotes as that should not be a string.

So just:

```
restart: on-failure
```

Comment: I have user and password `'USER': env('DB_USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),`

Comment: Not in the `DATABASES` settngs that you posted in the original comment, you don't. I've added a thought about the yaml restart policy. Otherwise, please edit the question to show the docker logs for the db container when it tries to start.